Is it possible to use Type 1 fonts and TrueType fonts in the same LaTeX document?
I have a Type 1 font of which I do not have a TrueType version, and a TrueType font of which I do not have a Type 1 version. Is there a straightforward way to use these two fonts in the same LaTeX document? The language of the document is German, so the characters ä, ö, ü and ß may appear in the text.
When using XeTeX or LuaTeX, you can of course select any TrueType font using fontspec. However, when changing the font encoding to T1 mid-document to use a Type 1 font, the ß will no longer work:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

Straße

{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont Straße}

\end{document}


On the other hand, I've read that pdfTeX is theoretically capable of handling TrueType fonts, but in practice this seems to be very cumbersome.

well you can use Stra\ss e with luatex (or define ß to do that)), but be aware that hyphenation can be wrong as the luatex patterns assume unicode. I would avoid it for longer texts.

Possible in pdfTeX ... yes; straightforward ... no.
